# Yeti with a microphone

Tags: meaning, punctuation, ambiguity

> We started interviewing a Yeti with a microphone.

How do we ensure that we mean the picture on the right and not  on the left?

[image]

And how would we describe this one?

[image]

**Edit,** from the comments:

- unlikely Yeti would hold the mic, so it is clear who is holding the mic. Replace Yeti with a person, say "Tom".
- we could write extra before/after sentences to clarify, but would want to keep it short as one sentence.
- it is important to clarify who is holding the mic.

Comment: @Spencer How would you describe each picture without ambiguity?

Comment: Add a whole new sentence clarifying who has the microphone.  Do you really require something different?

Comment: @Spencer we could, but how about in one sentence?

Comment: (L) We started interviewing a Yeti which had a microphone. //// [R] With the help of (/Using) a microphone, we started interviewing a Yeti. ////  [B] With the help of (/Using) a microphone, we started interviewing a Yeti. Which also had a microphone.

Comment: 1) We started interviewing a Yeti by using a microphone. 2) We started interviewing a Yeti with a microphone by using a microphone.

Comment: But I think it's worthwhile to note that in your original sentence, off-the-bat, most people would think of the picture on the right.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang of course, replace Yeti with a person, say "Tom".

Comment: In real writing, you wouldn't make the use of a microphone as important as the interview by putting it in the same sentence.

Comment: @Spencer it might be an important part of the story, to clarify that the microphone was used for the interview.

Comment: 'using the microphone, we began to interview the yeti.' 'Using our microphone, we began to interview the Yeti who had a mic of her own.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reader should be able to know from context, even if you don't add additional sentences.

But anyway, you could add a comma after the "Yeti":
"We started interviewing a Yeti with a microphone." = ambiguous
"We started interviewing a Yeti, with a microphone." = excludes the picture on the left
(You could also rearrange it: "We, with a microphone, started interviewing a Yeti.")

Or, you could change the "a" to "our" (which clarifies possession of the microphone):
"We started interviewing a Yeti with a microphone." = ambiguous
"We started interviewing a Yeti with our microphone." = still ambiguous, but more likely the picture on the right

If you really need to be clear on who's holding the microphone, maybe try something like:
"We handed the microphone to the Yeti and started interviewing him." = the picture on the left
"We held the microphone up to a Yeti and started interviewing him." = the picture on the right

If you wanted to convey the sense of the third picture, maybe:
"We started interviewing a Yeti, each party using separate microphones."

Comment: Last case: "We took out our microphone to interview the Yeti and darn, if he didn't have his own microphone."  I use "he" in a non-gender sense since, really, who can tell with a Yeti?